# TCL Format Command Returns Wrong UTF-8 Characters

Tags: tcl

I am implementing a socket client in TCL only. The server needs to be informed of the length of the message sent by the client, so I prepend the length of message with a utf-8 character of the message length. I converted the message length to utf-8 character using the TCL Format command.

However, the Format command does not always return the correct utf-8 character which confuses the server.
For example in the sample code below format returns § for 21 and 167:

```
% format %c 21
§
% format %c 167
§
```

Could it be that I am doing something wrong?

Comment: IMHO this is a bad idea. I recommend you send the length as basic digits instead.

Comment: @Peter thanks, that was that I did initially but the server (QT) receives the message as character array. So the digits are converted to their corresponding utf-8 code.

Comment: Have you tried formatting to a binary? I.e. if your string is in the variable `str` and you send the value `[binary format c [string length $str]]$str`? You're basically limited to 255 characters, but you don't get the conversion issues. (Not familiar with QT.)

Comment: Re your issue with format: I can't reproduce it and it shouldn't be happening: format simply returns a character for the given Unicode number, it doesn’t recode in any way.

Comment: @PeterLewerin, my observation is that problem occurs with non-printable characters. My computer runs windows 7 the tcl version is 8.6. I have tried your suggest with [binary format c [string length $str]]$str, but same issues.

Comment: Haven't a clue, then. Works fine for me on Win 7 / Tcl 8.6 (i.e. dumping on the command line works -- I have no QT code to try it on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The § should come from `format %c 167`; that's exactly as expected given that it is the [section sign character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign). By contrast, `format %c 21` should produce a [non-printable NAK character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acknowledgement_(data_networks)), though for some reason your terminal is rendering it differently. (I'm not sure what interpretation it is falling back to; it's not one that is listed in an encoding table that I have conveniently at hand.)

Tcl's probably doing exactly the right thing, especially as the NAK character is present in most common character encodings.

Comment: I am very grateful for your kind responses. The console printout problem remains but TCL is actually sending the right value. Since I don't need the console printout,I can say problem solved!